# Unable to launch App on iOs 9.1 Adobe Air (not all devices)

Tags: ios, actionscript, air, adobe

we have inhouse iOS app (created with adobe air). On some iPads we can't launch the app after installing. 
(iPad Air 2, iOS 9.1)

We get the following messages in console.

```
<Warning>: Binary is improperly signed.
<Warning>: Unable to register for exec notifications: No such process
<Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 1278: (os/kern) failure (5)
<Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x1643e6f40; pid: 1278>
<Warning>: exited due to an invalid code signature.
<Warning>: Application '(null)' exited for an unknown reason.
```

It looks like a certificate problem but on other devices we can install and run the application without any problems. We have created the cerficate on october 2015.

I would have been pleased if someone has any idea, what's going wrong.

Kind Regards

Comment: Looks like I have the issue here, did you come up with an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add UDID of all devices in provision profile. Than build your app again with this provision and test.